# Reactjs How to write the greater than 0 in jsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Reactjs How to write the greater than 0 in jsx?

this is my current code

```
return (
    {num > 0 ? (
       console.log('greater than 0')
    ):(console.log('less than zero')}
  )
```

Comment: May be try enclosing in a JSX tag like so: `return (num > 0 ? <div>greater than 0</div> : <div>less than zero</div>);` rather than `console.log`.

Comment: `return <>{num > 0 ? <div>greater</div> : <div>less than</div>}</>` definitely works.

Comment: Try to remove the `console.log` call and just leave the string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you wanna display the evaluation on screen? There is a clean way to do that.

```
const App = () => {
...// logic you want

    const comment = num > 0 ? 'greater than 0' : 'less than zero';
    return <p>{comment}</p>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 export default function App() {
  const num = 2;
  return (
   <div>
    {num > 0 ? <h1> Greater than Zero </h1> : <h1> Zero</h1>}
   </div>
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `>` by `&gt` and replace `<` by `&lt`

You can use the following code as a replacement :

```html
return (
    {num &gt 0 ? (
       console.log('greater than 0')
    ):(console.log('less than zero')}
  )
```

Comment: Why I am getting redline or error?

Comment: `num={{length &gt 0 ? true : false}}`

Comment: It should be like this : num={{num.length > 0 ? true : false}}

Answer (score 0):

We have to first validate num exists and then do the conditional checking if it exists.

```
return (
{num && num > 0 ? (
   console.log('greater than 0')
):(console.log('less than zero'))})
```

Also you were missing a ')' at the end, which was a syntactical error

Comment: What if `num` is `0`?

Comment: @Alastair the OP's logic isn't that accurate , its either greater than 0 or not greater than 0 (instead of less than 0) . yea but with his logic, if num is 0, the output is less than zero